# Migrating a rails/rake application to a new server without resetting all passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm not much of a Rails guy, so this may be a no-brainer:

We run Chili Project for project management in a mod-passenger environment, using MySQL for the database. We changed servers once in moving there from Redmine, and I would like to now migrate to a virtual machine. I have the virtual machine up and running, but--like the last time--the **username/password combos don't work without a reset**.

I'm guessing this means there is a stored secret that needs to also be copied to the new server, but I don't know what/where that is. Any Rails/Rake gurus have an easy answer for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have become a non-issue. In two separate migrations, the passwords stayed consistent on one, not the other. The only difference between the two (same application, same data, same OS, same method of migration) was the version of ruby, gems, and friends.